# Work done in an elastic collision in the following case

Tags: collision, kinetic-theory

In a perfectly elastic collision the two bodies that collide will end up maintaining their complessive initial momenta and kinetic energy. Basically if body A impacts against body B at 10 m/s (with both bodies having a mass of 1 kg) it’ll bounce back still going at 10 m/s - maintaining therefore its original KE of 50 J and momentum of 10 kg • m/s.

However there’s a thing that escapes me, or better that sounds wrong to my mind: if the change of energy is null, then the work done is also null no? After all energy isn’t vectorial. But wouldn’t this mean that in the collision the force exerted on both objects somehow didn’t do any work?

Comment: Work done in compression is given back in work done in relaxation.